# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, setup.py, google-ai-platform

I am trying to train my object detection model using google AI platform, when I run the training I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE1cS.png)

I have no problem when running the training my local machine.

I also run pip list command and I already have setuptools installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOVNE.png)

How to solve this problem?

Here is the setup.py from the Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API:

```
"""Setup script for object_detection with TF2.0."""
import os
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    # Required for apache-beam with PY3
    'avro-python3',
    'apache-beam',
    'pillow',
    'lxml',
    'matplotlib',
    'Cython',
    'contextlib2',
    'tf-slim',
    'six',
    'pycocotools',
    'lvis',
    'scipy',
    'pandas',
    'tf-models-official>=2.5.1',
    'tensorflow_io',
    'keras',
    'pyparsing==2.4.7',  # TODO(b/204103388)
    'sacrebleu<=2.2.0'  # https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/issues/209
]

setup(
    name='object_detection',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=(
        [p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('object_detection')] +
        find_packages(where=os.path.join('.', 'slim'))),
    package_dir={
        'datasets': os.path.join('slim', 'datasets'),
        'nets': os.path.join('slim', 'nets'),
        'preprocessing': os.path.join('slim', 'preprocessing'),
        'deployment': os.path.join('slim', 'deployment'),
        'scripts': os.path.join('slim', 'scripts'),
    },
    description='Tensorflow Object Detection Library',
    python_requires='>3.6',
)
```